# Value of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$$T(1, -2, 3)=(1,2,3,4)$$

$$T(2,1,-1) = (1,0,-1,0)$$

Find the transformation of $(-8,1,-3)$

Is there a method to use to solve this problem besides just staring at the numbers and trying to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: Find a way to write $(-8,1,-3)$ as a linear combination of the two vectors given. i.e. find $\lambda, \mu$ such that $(-8,1,-3) = \lambda(1,-2,3)+\mu(2,1,-1)$.

This can be done by splitting the above vector equation into components, solving two simultaneous equations for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ (in the first and second co-ordinates, say) and then checking that the given values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ satisfy the above equation in the last co-ordinate.

Once you have this, you can use the linearity of $T$ to evaluate:$$T(-8,1,-3)=T(\lambda(1,-2,3)+\mu(2,1,-1))$$

Comment: I get it,thank you very much

Comment: @Owen No problem, happy to help!